# Is it possible to use splinter to select option by text (for instance when select options have no value)?

Tags: splinter

```
<select id = 'foo' name = 'foo'>
    <option>aaaaa</option>
    <option>bbbbb</option>
    <option>ccccc</option>
    <option>ddddd</option>
</select>
```

It seems in the command "browser.select("foo", value)" a value is needed.

Is there a workaround for this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible find an option by text and then click on it:

```
browser.find_option_by_text('bbbbb').first.click()
```

I hope this can help you.